# Define global constant with username in Obj-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I want to define a constant file path that includes whoever's username (e.g. `/Users/username/Desktop`...in my specific case it's a directory I create at `/var/spool/FolderICreate/username`).

What's the best way of declaring this constant so my other classes can recognize it? I currently have a globals.h file to include for the classes that need to see the globals, but I'm not sure how to set the value.  `#define` obviously needs a hardcoded string literal, and I'm not sure if I can or how I would set the string using `extern const NSString*`.  I feel like this shouldn't be hard, but I'm at a loss.

-- EDIT --

As people have rightly pointed out, my code was unnecessary because I can get the username with `NSUserName`, etc, so I've removed it.  But I think people are missing the point of my question.  I can see there are multiple ways to get the pathname I want--how do I declare that as a constant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [NSPathUtilities](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/NSPathUtilities) before you re-implement a bunch of functionality that's already provided in Foundation framework. You'll find a bunch of methods there specifically for what you're trying to do.

To answer the question you actually asked, there's no straightforward way to declare a variable as a constant and then change its value at runtime... That sort of defeats the purpose of telling the compiler it's constant. Simply declare the variable in a header file as an `extern NSString *` and only set it once. :-)

Answer (score 3):

To your revised question, as Kaelin notes, you don't want a constant. A constant in C is something defined at compile time, and you don't know what the value is at compile time.

You don't want a variable for this problem. You want a static function. Foundation provides many that do things similar to what you want. If you want something else, make your own static function `MYDirectoryForStuff()`.

Do not create non-constant global variables. That way lies madness. You then have to verify that they get initialized before they are used, which leads to all kinds of subtle bugs. If you use a static function, then it can easily be self-initializing.

Answer (score 2):

You should never make any assumptions about where the user's home folder might be.

The correct way to retrieve the path to the current user's home folder is

`NSHomeDirectory()`

If you wish to access one of the standard subfolders of the user's home folder, don't make any assumption about their location either, but use

`NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomain()`

to retrieve them. For example, to get the documents folder:

```
NSArray *searchPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomain(
    NSDocumentDirectory, 
    NSUserDomainMask, 
    YES
);
NSLog(@"The documents folder is at %@", [searchPaths objectAtIndex:0]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the information, I'll take it into consideration, but your answer didn't really answer my actual question.

Answer (score 0):

The Foundation framework has a function for this: [`NSUserName()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html).

Comment: Thanks, that helps simplify the code, but I still don't know how I would define the global that way.  Using `extern const *NSString filePath`, I can't use `[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"/Users/%@/Desktop", NSUsername()]`, so that doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: @Katie: Just call `NSUserName` whenever you need the username -- no need for a global variable.

Comment: It's in a filepath that is redundant to hard code through multiple classes, hence defining the global.

Comment: @Katie: What's the difference between using a global variable or a function?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand that's what you were getting at.  Your answer/comments didn't mention anything about the function I would need to write.